# WinForms equivalent of performSelectorOnMainThread in Objective-C

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I haven't done much multithreading before and now find the need to do some background work and keep the UI responsive. I have the following code.

```
data.ImportProgressChanged += new 
     DataAccess.ImportDelegate(data_ImportProgressChanged);

Thread importThread = new Thread(
       new ThreadStart(data.ImportPeopleFromFAD));
importThread.IsBackground = true;
importThread.Start();

void data_ImportProgressChanged(int progress)
{
    toolStripProgressBar.Value = progress;
}

//In my data object I have 
public void ImportPeopleFromFAD()
{
    ImportProgressChanged(someInt);
}
```

But the UI doesn't get updated since the `ImportProgressChanged()` call is made on the background thread. In objective C I know you can use performSelectorOnMainThread and pass it a method to call using the main thread. What is the equivalent way of calling `ImportProgressChanged()` from the main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming Windows Forms.) You can use [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) or [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) - but a cleaner way *may* be to use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to start with.

In WPF you'd use a [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) instead of `Control.Invoke`, btw. See this [WPF threading model guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) for more details.

EDIT: Personally I probably wouldn't bother testing `InvokeRequired` first - I'd just call `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`. If you're already "on" the right thread it won't do any significant harm.

For progress bars, however, `BackgroundWorker` is definitely the way forward.

Comment: So there is no simple way to have 1 thread do something in another thread? The Control.Invoke solution that @Henk Holterman illustrated seems like such a mess, and specific only to controls.

Comment: toolStripProgressBar indicates WinForms

Comment: @jamone: It's not specific to controls; it's specific to anything implementing `ISynchronizeInvoke`. Basically there has to be some support from the other thread - you shouldn't just expect to be able to hijack any random thread at will...

Comment: @Jamone: you cannot break into a thread, it will have to poll (MessageLoop). Control.Invoke is the gateway, messy as it is.

Comment: I went the BackgroundWorker route.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating the GUI, data_ImportProgressChanged should throw an exception when it <strike>gets called</strike> changes the progressbar.

The shortest change is to use Control.InvokeRequired and .Invoke(), but the [Backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) was especially created for this scenario .

If you want to solve it in the data object you will have to make that depend on the GUI so its better to solve this in the handler:

```
void data_ImportProgressChanged(int progress)
{
    if (toolStripProgressBar.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Action<int> a = new Action(data_ImportProgressChanged);
        toolStripProgressBar.Invoke(a, progress);
    }
    else
        toolStripProgressBar.Value = progress;
}
```

Comment: It will only throw an exception if you're running in the debugger, IIRC.

Comment: I thought throwing exceptions was an expensive operation?

Comment: @jamone: Starting .NET 2 they built a protective layer into WinForms to detect cross-threading early. When you program correctly, nothing is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You already have your answer but I'll add my solution anyway:

```
void data_ImportProgressChanged(int progress)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new Action<int>(data_ImportProgressChanged),progress);
        return;
    }

    toolStripProgressBar.Value = progress;
}
```